# Built-In Actions UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: uidocument, uidocumentbrowservc

Is it possible to control which built-in actions appear in the UIDocumentBrowserActionAvailabilityMenu / UIDcoumentBrowserActionAvailabilityNavigationBar associated with a UIDocumentBrowserViewController?

I'd like to convert my app's custom browser to the UIDocumentBrowserViewController.  Although I'm new to UIDocumentBrowserViewController, its sharing feature seems inconsistent with selling in-app purchases which, in my app, can be represented as a documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add custom actions, but you don't have control over the built-in actions